# how to prevent convert big numbers as varchar example 1444092 is 1.44409e+006

Tags: sql, case-when, sqltransaction, sql-convert

this is my final query

```
select Codigo,  Indicador,
case when Indicador like '%Porcentaje%' then cast((round((([Valor Censo Elegido]/@cantidad)*100),0)) as varchar(50))+' %' else cast([Valor Censo Elegido]as varchar(50)) end as [Valor Censo Elegido],
case when Indicador like '%Porcentaje%' then cast((round((([Valor Censo Actual]/@cantidad)*100),0))as varchar(50))+' %' else cast([Valor Censo Actual]as varchar(50)) end as [Valor Censo Actual]
--case when Indicador like '%Porcentaje%' then round((([Valor Censo Elegido]/@cantidad)*100),0)  else ([Valor Censo Elegido]) end as [Valor Censo Elegido],
--case when Indicador like '%Porcentaje%' then round((([Valor Censo Actual]/@cantidad)*100),0) else ([Valor Censo Actual]) end as [Valor Censo Actual]

from  #unionfinal
```

but big numbers convert something as  1.44409e+006
and i need  when indicador contain word porcentaje this was calculated and char '%' was added, it converts but i got this bug

working on sql 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, CAST to a DECIMAL number, then to a VARCHAR:

```
cast(cast((round(([Valor Censo Elegido]/@cantidad)*100),0) as decimal(50,0)) as varchar(50))+' %'
```